# proving Cauchy sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence so that $|a_N - a_{N-1}| < 1/(2^n)$ need to prove that $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I started by saying:

$$|a_m-a_n| = |a_m - (a_{m-1}) + (a_{m-1}) - (a_{m-2}) + (a_{m-2}) - \dotsb - a_n| = $$

$$= |(a_m - a_{m-1}) + (a_{m-1} -a_{m-2}) + ... (a_{n+1} - a_n)| \leq $$

$$\leq  |a_m - a_{m-1}| + ... + |a_{n+1} - a_n| = 1/(2^m) + 1/(2^{m-1}) + \dotsb + 1/(2^{n+1}) \leq  \frac{m-n}{2^(n+1)}$$

I got stuck here becasue I can't get rid of $m$, in order to find an $N$ that for any $n>N : |a_m-a_n| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Assume WLOG $m\geq n$. We have $$|a_m-a_n|\le \sum_{k=n+1}^m |a_k-a_{k-1}|\le\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty|a_k-a_{k-1}|\le\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}.$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Please use mathjax for readability

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I'm sorry, I don't know how to write in latex, I tried my best to make it readable.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch can you please explain what you did there?

Comment: @DarkLeader Sebastiano has edited: you can click 'edit' now and see the markup he used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have gotten to the point $$ |a_m-a_n|\le \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} |a_k-a_{k-1}|\le \sum_{k=n+1}^m 2^{-k},$$ but you have stopped because the sup bound $(m-n) 2^{-(n+1)}$ depends on $m$ so is useless. However since the exponential series converges rapidly, the fact that the number of terms increases with $m$ should be no impediment, and indeed there is a simple bound that doesn't depend on $m.$ As Maximillian Janisch suggested in the comments, just let the series go to infinity: $$ \sum_{k=n+1}^m 2^{-k}\le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 2^{-k} = 2^{-n}$$

Comment: what do I do after? I just learned this subject, sorry if its a dumb question.

Comment: @DarkLeader Choose $N$ large enough so that   $2^{-N}<\epsilon$. What’s been shown implies that for $m,n> N,$ $|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon.$

Comment: i can't say choose an N large enough, i need to find a value for N and then say that for $m,n > N$ , $|a_m - a_n| < \epsilon$

Comment: @DarkLeader I’m saying pick any value large enough so that $2^{-N}< \epsilon$. For example the first natural number larger than $\log_2(1/\epsilon)$.